# Mongo DB Save tries to insert instead of update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

I am doing a Mongo Schema.save(), which should automatically do an upsert, but it insists on trying to do an insert and then errors with

```
E11000 duplicate key error index
```

This is the Node function that does the save:

```
exports.ImpdateSave = function(req, res) {
    var theImpdate = new Impdate(req.body)
    if (theImpdate){
        var impdateId = req.params.id;
        console.log("Node API Impdate: ", theImpdate);
        console.log("Node API Impdate ID: ", impdateId);
        theImpdate.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.send(400);
            }
            res.send(200);
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(400).send('There was no person data in the request to update. Please try again!');    
    }
};
```

Why is it unable to find the document when it does the initial search before the insert/update, but then finds it when it does the insert?

Output from Console:

```
Node API Impdate:  { _id: 5481c33cd8bf24f4235cff35,
  _creator: 54679200502e901427fec6de,
  name: 'XXXXX',
  address: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  __v: 0}

Node API Impdate ID:  5481c33cd8bf24f4235cff35
{ [MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: fullstack-dev.impdates.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('5481c33cd8bf24f4235cff35') }]
   name: 'MongoError',
   code: 11000,
   err: 'insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: fullstack-dev.impdates.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId(\'5481c33cd8bf24f4235cff35\')
  }' }
```

Comment: What's the value of the duplicate key? I assume it's an empty string, or null, right? In any case, this is a dangerous approach - you *must* re-fetch the object before inserting; your object `theImpdate` comes from the client entirely, and could have any id, even one that doesn't belong to the authenticated user which would enable any user to update data that doesn't belong to them.

Comment: Nope. Have added the console.log output from the function above...

Comment: Hm, maybe the JS driver uses different criteria to identify an update. Does re-fetching the object first solve the problem?

Comment: I assume you're using Mongoose?  Its `save` doesn't do an upsert like you're thinking. When you create a new `Impdate` object like you're doing here, it will always treat it as a new doc, even if the contained `_id` value already exists.

Comment: I am using mongoose.  So how do I get the object from the req.body and update Mongo?

Comment: Either `findOne` the doc by its `_id`, apply the new values from the body and `save`, or use `findByIdAndUpdate`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. Put that as an answer and I'll make it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose's `save` doesn't do an upsert like you're thinking. When you create a new `Impdate` object like you're doing here, it will always treat it as a new doc, even if the contained `_id` value already exists.

Instead, either [`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) the doc by its `_id`, apply the new values from the body and `save`, or use [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate).

Comment: All working sweetly now!  (After a few axtra tweaks for other bugs!)  Thanks for the help @JohnnyHK